# Cannot read property 'getExtension' of undefined - While running file in debug mode

Tags: visual-studio-code

When i try to run a file in debug mode (integrated terminal), i get this error. I only get it for only one workspace, other workspaces seem working.[vscode python debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Gt90.png)

Comment: It worked. no idea what was wrong. :)

Comment: how did you fix this in the end?

Comment: Could not figure that out. I tried removing some of the extensions so that could have done the trick but not sure.

Answer (score 3):

I just got this issue and it was because of something wrong I had typed in my envFile.

(This is what I had in my `launch.json`)...

```
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/.env-debug"
```

I believe it was because I tried to 'read' a VAR in the envFile more than once.  Ridiculous VS Code bug I think.

```
VAR=some-value
OTHER_VAR=${VAR}
ANOHTER_VAR=${VAR}
```